# Cannot connect to MySQL server on *.*.*.* (10060)

Tags: mysql, rhel7

I have installed MySQL 5.7.11 in my RHEL server 7.0. I am able to access the database using command prompt but I am not able to remotely login it through MySQL workbench. the `my.cnf` file is placed in `/etc` folder which looks like this

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
#max_connections = 250
[mysqld]
max_connections = 250
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
join_buffer_size = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

bind-address = 10.106.100.230
lower_case_table_names = 1

I have even given grant access to root user but still of no use.
```

Comment: Check your fireware rules, open port `3306` for external connection. Your question maybe duplicate with this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94102/remote-mysql-connection-fails-10060-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-domain

Comment: see the link :https://superuser.com/questions/1364906/mysql-error-10060-oracle-linux-mysql-8 I solve my Problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 cases where you can face this issue either the machine from where you are trying to connect is not whitelisted on the server's firewall or the MySQL server is down

In your case it's probably a networking issue so here are some things you want to check:

1- Verify if each machine can ping the other and verify if the port is open ( use `Telnet`for exemple )

2- Make sure your firewall is not blocking connection to your MySQL listening port if so add it to the unblock/exception list of firewall with `iptables`

3- Remove `bind-address = 10.106.100.230` from your `my.cnf` file

4- Ask your question in Unix/Linux forum ; you will get more help